# iOS - uitabbarcontroller with 2 collection views

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabbarController` with 2 `UICollectionViews`. 
Each `UIcollectionView` has cell with an `UIImageView`.

When `UITabbarController` is loaded, the `UICollectionView` with default tab is loaded correctly. When I switch the tab to other `UICollectionView` it's cells are loaded but it doesn't render any of it's `UIImageView` contents.
Every data source as well as delegate methods are being called for the other `UICollectionView`. 
This is happening only in `iOS9`.
It's working fine in `iOS7` and `iOS8`.
What can be the reason?

Thanks.